# How to pass the ajax value to the controller and get the data from db?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#csubmit1').on('click',function (event) {
      // alert("test");
      event.preventDefault();
      var formData = {
      orderfrom1: $("#orderfrom1").val(),
      orderto1: $("#orderto1").val(),
      agentlist1: $("#ag1").val(),
    };
      
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/obwirelessreports",
            data:formData,
 success:function (data) {
                $('#search_change1').html(data);
            }

        });
      
    });
});
```

Controller.php

```
$details=$this->input->post();
        
            $data["orderfrom1"]=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($details['order_from']));
            $data["orderto1"]=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($details['order_to']));
            $data["agentlist1"]=$this->Maindata->wiresearch1($details);
```

Model.php

```
        $orderfrom=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data2['order_from']));
        $orderto=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data2['order_to']));
        $agent_list = implode(', ', array_map(function($val){return sprintf("'%s'", $val);}, $data2["agentlist1"]));
```

I don't Know how to pass the data from ajax to the controller . Is this the right way ? i have tried using the data in a single array but it is not working . What is the Changes that i should make ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the parameters `orderfrom,orderto,agentlist` but reading `orderfrom,orderto,agentlist`, they have to match exactly.

```
        $data["orderfrom1"]=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($details['order_from1']));
        $data["orderto1"]=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($details['order_to1']));
        $data["agentlist1"]=$this->Maindata->wiresearch1($details);
```

I don't know what `data2` in the Model but the keys may have to match as well.